# How to send data from controller to another controller in yii2

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii2

Can i get data that i got from controller, and then send it to another controller (in the same folder) in Yii2?

this is my SiteController:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
...
 $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
 $reg_res = $data['ColoringForm']['region'];
...
```

i want to send $reg_res to my DataController:

```
 public function actionShowdata()
{
$reg_res ??
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post array data is not possible to send from on controller to another controller but you can send it through parameters.

Try below code

```
$this->redirect(array('controller/action', 'param1'=>'value1', 'param2'=>'value2',...)
```

Comment: i am newbie in yii2.. can you help me how to implement it in my code?

Comment: is that possble to send data without redirect to another page?
i mean just send the data

Comment: You will get the post array like this.                                                       $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
$reg_res = $data['ColoringForm']['region'];                                                                                                    $this->redirect(array('controller/action', 'reg_res'=>$reg_res);                                                                                 You can access this parameter in your action through params

Comment: Yes , it is but using other approach like session

Comment: thank you very much... i use session approach and it's work :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to run a separate action within the same request:

`Yii::$app->runAction('controller/show-data', ['param1'=>'value1', 'param2'=>'value2']);`

Comment: is that possible to send data without redirect to another page? i mean just send the data

Comment: The above will do that. No redirect.